# Select2 Scroll Current Selection Span to Bottom on every select (closeOnSelect = False)

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/776660/

I have a Multi-Select `select2` control that has a fixed height of 1 line. As I select new multiple items, they get added but the span doesn't move the cursor to the end of the "current" box. The Current Selector is stuck on the current line. It only moves to the end once I leave the selection process.

I tried this code, which you can comment on/off to see the original problem:

```
/* Scroll CurrSel SPAN to bottom on every Select2 Select event */
/* Comment/Toggle this ON/OFF for testing */
$('#dropdown').on("select2:selecting", function(e) { 
    var currselspan = $('#dropdown').next().find('.select2-selection--multiple').first();
    console.log('scrollTop = ' + $(currselspan).scrollTop() + ' scrollHeight = ' + $(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
    $(currselspan).scrollTop($(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
});
```

This is an improvement, but there's still an issue: the first time a new entry goes to the next line, the Curr Selection span doesn't scroll. It only starts scrolling *after a newline entry already went in*.

**GOAL: Any time "a newline entry goes in," auto-scroll to the end of the Current Selection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below line to your method.

```
$(".select2-selection--multiple input").focus();
```

So your method will be

```
$('#dropdown').on("select2:selecting", function(e) { 
    var currselspan = $('#dropdown').next().find('.select2-selection--multiple').first();
    console.log('scrollTop = ' + $(currselspan).scrollTop() + ' scrollHeight = ' + $(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
    $(currselspan).scrollTop($(currselspan).prop('scrollHeight'));
    $(".select2-selection--multiple input").focus();
});
```

You can test it here.. http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/776765/

Answer (score 1):

this code working fine for my side, I hope this will help you.

```
$('#selectmultiple').select2({
    closeOnSelect: false
})
 .on('select2:selecting', e => $(e.currentTarget).data('scrolltop', $('.select2-results__options').scrollTop()))
 .on('select2:select', e => $('.select2-results__options').scrollTop($(e.currentTarget).data('scrolltop')));
```